# Dog parks data/shapefile

Tags: openstreetmap

Where can I get data about dog park areas in cities around the world? I wanted to use Overpass API but couldn't find the amenity key for it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to look at the key = leisure.

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:leisure%3Ddog_park

this query will give you all the dogparks (if mapped!)

```
/*
This has been generated by the overpass-turbo wizard.
The original search was:
“leisure=dog_park”
*/
[out:json][timeout:25];
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “leisure=dog_park”
  node["leisure"="dog_park"]({{bbox}});
  way["leisure"="dog_park"]({{bbox}});
  relation["leisure"="dog_park"]({{bbox}});
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```